# Is delaying security concerns towards the end of the application development cycle a good approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

As we are going to developing some public API for other applications to integrate with, someone suggests that we should delay the security stuff until the methods of the API have been done, so the third party application will have something to work with! Is it a good approach to resolve the issue, or should we put security in place and then develop the API itself?

EDIT:

The issue here is the cost.Let's say that if you have it in the first place, I think that you won't have to revisit the APIs to make changes due to security stuff, especially with the third party application, which is maintained by another team.
If we delay it until everything has been done and integrated, then the other team has to modify and change code as well.

So from your experience, what will cost less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have the **design complete** from the start, including security. Changing the design later will cost much more. **Implementation** may well be either delayed or incomplete at first.

If you don't e.g. know the granularity of access rights you will have to do a lot of redesign when you later find out that it must go beyond table access or beyond SIDU and in fact work a row level..

Putting in dummy functions and working out the details of **how** to implement the real thing later is more or less free but to do that you first need to know **what** the customer needs and plan for it!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on...

- The overall risk as it relates to the security for your API.  We talking banking/life-and-death or cat pics?  The more risk, the more I'd want to address that upfront.
- The general level of skill and experience of your team.  Folks with more experience are less likely to paint themselves into a corner.
- Applicable experience securing an API.  If it's everyone's first go at this, I'd at least do detailed planning upfront.

I'm all for kicking the can on security, secure authentication, ACLs, etc. when possible.  But don't just say, "Let's do it later" without getting a good handle on the risk that decision might incur.  In all likelihood those discussions will yield a viable path forward should you have to start to implement the security concerns sooner than planned.

Answer (score 1):

Security is a CROSSCUTTING concern, which means, it penetrates(and should) every level of the architecture. Why not use Basic Auth and share the key with your third party app developers instead?

Security must always be a concern. It won't help delaying if your APIs are flawless and your security system is flawed.